# Is it possible to hover on the pieces of a LineSegment distinctly in three.js to identify those with only one geometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created two examples of drawing lines in `three.js`, one uses different `geometry` and `material` and another uses only one `geometry` and one `material`. The links of the fidlles are: https://jsfiddle.net/sounakgarai/6reawwot/4/ and https://jsfiddle.net/sounakgarai/2xL70me3/ respectively.

I can hover on the lines in the first example and can see them change the `material` `color` on mouseover. And in the second example when I hover, the whole `lineMesh` gets its `color` changed as there is only one `material`.

Now what I would like to do is to use only one `geometry` like in the second example. But I want to see an effect which is seen in the first example: all the different pieces of the `LineSegment` (of the second example) I want to see those getting hovered in a way so that I can identify those distinctly (but I don't want to use different `geometry` for that).

Is it possible to achieve?

The important thing is that when I use multiple `geometry`, it makes the browser hang and go slow while rendering a large model which has considerably large number of members. And I also want to `render` multiple `three.js` models in different div elements in a page in future. So it may make the browser go more slow while rendering them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide vertex colors instead of the material color. Like this -

```
var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors});
```

And for each vertex, push the corresponding color. Like this -

```
geometry.colors.push(new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"), new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"));
```

And in the mouse hover handler, you need to get the index of the currently intersected line and change the color of that vertex. Like this -

```
intersects[0].object.geometry.colors[intersects[0].index].setHex(0xff0000);

let nextIndex = intersects[0].index + (intersects[0].index % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1 );
intersects[0].object.geometry.colors[nextIndex].setHex(0xff0000);
intersects[0].object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Here is the simplified code based on your second version -

```
     var container, scene, camera, renderer;
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        var intersected;

        init();

        animate();

        function guid() {
            function s4() {
                return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                    .toString(16)
                    .substring(1);
            }
            return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
                s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
        }

        function init() {

            container = document.getElementById("myDiv");

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf7f7f7);

            var WIDTH = container.clientWidth,
                HEIGHT = container.clientHeight;

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
            renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 20000);
            camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);


            var nsize = 1, nspace = 5, nrange;
            nrange = nsize * nspace;
            var i, j, x, y, z = 0;

            var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors});
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            for (i = 0; i <= nsize; i++) {
                for (j = 0, x = 0, y = 0; j <= nsize; j++) {

                    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z), new THREE.Vector3(x, y + nspace, z));
                    geometry.colors.push(new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"), new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"));

                    x += nspace;
                }
                for (j = 0, x = 0, y = 0; j <= nsize; j++) {

                    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z), new THREE.Vector3(x + nspace, y, z));
                   geometry.colors.push(new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"), new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"));

                    y += nspace;
                }
                z += nspace;
            }

            y = -10;

            for (i = 0; i <= nsize; i++) {
                for (j = 0, x = 0, z = 0; j <= nsize; j++) {

                    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z), new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z + nspace));

                    geometry.colors.push(new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"), new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"));

                    x += nspace;
                }
                for (j = 0, x = 0, z = 0; j <= nsize; j++) {

                    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z), new THREE.Vector3(x + nspace, y, z));
                     geometry.colors.push(new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"), new THREE.Color("rgb(0, 0, 255)"));

                    z += nspace;
                }
                y += nspace;
            }

            var lineMesh = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, lineMaterial);
            lineMesh.name = guid();

            lineMesh.position.x = -(nsize * nspace) / 2;
            lineMesh.position.y = -(nsize * nspace) / 2;
            lineMesh.position.z = -(nsize * nspace) / 2;

            scene.add(lineMesh);

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            // Render the scene.
            render();

        }



        function onMouseMove(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            // calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
            // (-1 to +1) for both components

            mouse.x = (event.clientX / container.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - (event.clientY / container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;

            if (mouse !== null && camera !== null) {

                var ray = new THREE.Raycaster();
                ray.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

                var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(scene.children);
                if (intersects.length > 0) {


                    intersects[0].object.geometry.colors[intersects[0].index].setHex(0xff0000);

let nextIndex = intersects[0].index + (intersects[0].index % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1 );

    intersects[0].object.geometry.colors[nextIndex].setHex(0xff0000);
    intersects[0].object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
             }
            }

        }

        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        container.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
```

Alternative of the raycaster, you can use GPU picking to identify the intersected line.

Comment: Yes, this helped. One more thing that I achieved is when the mouse is not hovering on the pieces of the LineSegment, the initial color is set.

Comment: You just have to save the initial color somewhere and restore this in same way when the mouse isn't hovering to any line.

Comment: Sourov, one thing I would like to achieve that is the accuracy of the mouse cursor while raycasting. I see that the pieces of the LineSegment gets hovered even when the mouse cursor is not accurately on the pieces but in a distance. You can have a look at it. Can you help fixing this?

Comment: If you provide me a jsfiddle i can have a look. Or better ask a new question so that others can have a look as well.

Comment: You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656645/how-can-i-achieve-accuracy-of-raycaster-while-mouse-hover-on-different-pieces-of

Answer (score 1):

An option with `THREE.BufferGeometry()`, `THREE.LineSegments()` and `.vertexColors = THREE.VertexColors`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var points = [
  new THREE.Vector3(-5, 5, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(),
  new THREE.Vector3(),
  new THREE.Vector3(5, 5, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(5, 5, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(5, -5, 0)
];

var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
geom.addAttribute("color", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .5, .5, .5, 1, 0, 1]), 3)); // we'll change this color attribute
geom.addAttribute("colorBase", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .5, .5, .5, 1, 0, 1]), 3)); // this attribute contains original colors for restoring
var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});
var line = new THREE.LineSegments(geom, mat);
scene.add(line);

// all of those variables are for re-use
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects = [];
var oldIndex = -1;
var col = new THREE.Color();

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(line);
  if (intersects.length === 0) return;
  let idx = intersects[0].index;
  if (idx !== oldIndex) highlightSegment(idx, 0xFFFF00);
}

function highlightSegment(idx, color) {
  setColor(idx, color);
  if (oldIndex !== -1) {
    restoreColor();
  }
  line.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
  oldIndex = idx; // save current index as an old one
}

function setColor(idx, color) { // change color for the current segment
  let idxNear = idx % 2 === 0 ? idx + 1 : idx - 1; // 
  // if 'idx' is an index of the start point in a segment, then its pair will be idx + 1, 
  // otherwise is idx - 1.
  col.set(color);
  let colors = line.geometry.attributes.color;
  colors.setXYZ(idx, col.r, col.g, col.b); // a very useful method of 'THREE.BufferAttribute()'
  colors.setXYZ(idxNear, col.r, col.g, col.b);
}

function restoreColor() { // restore the original color for the old segment
  let oldIndexNear = oldIndex % 2 === 0 ? oldIndex + 1 : oldIndex - 1;
  let colors = line.geometry.attributes.color;
  let colorBase = line.geometry.attributes.colorBase;
  colors.copyAt(oldIndex, colorBase, oldIndex); // another useful method of 'THREE.BufferAttribute()'
  colors.copyAt(oldIndexNear, colorBase, oldIndexNear);
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the material of a single LineSegment if you use a single geometry, but what you could do is overlay an extra LineSegment added dynamically on top of the segment you want to highlight, which I think will produce the effect you are looking for.

You can achieve that by creating a material with no [depthTest](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material):

`material.depthTest=false`

Which will always appear on top of the geometry that has a material with depthTest.