# How can I achieve accuracy of raycaster while mouse hover on different pieces of a LineSegment?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created one example to draw a `LineSegment` in `three.js`. I have applied `vertexColors` to its `material` and pushed `color` for vertices. Now when I hover on all the different pieces of the `LineSegment` I change the `color` of that vertex (along with the next or previous vertex depending on the order it got pushed in the `geometry.vertices` array so that a line gets its `color` changed, you will understand once you see the code) that gets picked by the `raycaster`.

The jsfiddle link is here. https://jsfiddle.net/sounakgarai/tedmc2f0/3/

Now the issue is that the hovering is not accurate; a piece of the `Linesegment` gets its `color` changed even when the mouse cursor is in a far distance from it (you will be able to see it when you run it). I would like to see the accuracy in this case. The piece of `LineSegment` should change the `color` when the mouse cursor is accurately on it.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't take in count, that your container is not at the [0, 0] position on the screen.

As an option, you can use `.getBoundingClientRect()` method to get the bounding rect of your container and then subtract it from the mouse coordinates you get in your listener.

```
var rect;
. . .

// in the listener
rect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect();

mouse.x = ((event.clientX - rect.left) / container.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = -((event.clientY - rect.top) / container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/oka0jkk5/) example

PS Just for your information, interface of jsfiddle.net has the `Tidy` button, which makes the code well-formed and thus much more readable.

Comment: The problem is still there. You can just check it on observing minutely . Now it is happening for the right side of the objects unlike before applying this when it happened for left side of the objects.

Comment: @SounakGarai At least for me, my jsfiddle example works perfectly fine.

Comment: I checked your fiddle in several different machines but the problem remains. I can not add a screenshot as stack overflow does not allow to do so. If I could, I could have shown you the issue.

Comment: @SounakGarai `THREE.Raycaster()` works with some precision for lines, you can play around with `.linePrecision` parameter of it.

Comment: Yea, with use of linePrecision it is working better, though not accurate enough.

Comment: Instead of `container.clientWidth` I used `rect.width` and `rect.height` instead of `container.clientHeight` and used `rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect()` and it worked better.