# Change color of a single line of a wireframe rendered object in three.js

Tags: jquery, three.js

**Hi, my name is Giuliano** and this is the first question of my life on this website :)

I have generated in a canvas a **CircleBufferGeometry** rendered as a #fff wireframe on a #000 black background; the rendering is stable and the scene is **without errors**.

Now i'm trying to **select just one** of the rendered wireframe **lines** and change its color. **My final goal** is to create a circle with **60 vertex lines** (lines that goes from the center to the edge of the object) and every second alternate the color of just 1 line as a simulation of a **clock hand.**

This is the code i now have visible [on my work in progress website](http://nogrid.co):

```js
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
{ color: 0xfefefe, wireframe: true, opacity: 0.5 } );

     init();
     function addMesh() {
    if ( mesh !== undefined ) {

     scene.remove( mesh );
     geometry.dispose();
          
    }
        
  geometry = geometries[ options.Geometry ];
  geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
        
 var scaleFactor = 1160 / geometry.boundingSphere.radius;
        
 geometry.scale( scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor );
 mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
 scene.add( mesh );
        
   }
```

**The ideal solution would be a jQuery selector (or whatever selector) that allows me to target the line i want among an array of lines and use an increasing value to cycle through them.**

I thought I could use an inwards vertex normal helper (colored in red) to simulate the effect but i lack in knowledge and really don't know how to apply some ideas yet... I just started experimenting in Three.js :)

*Every help is appreciated, sorry for my yet shallow understanding of basic mechanics.
Giuliano*

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48658878/4045502) and its jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rough concept of how you can do it:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var segs = 60;
var baseVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 5, 0);
var axisVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
var step = THREE.Math.degToRad(6);
var vertices = [];
for (var i = 0; i < segs; i++) {
  vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3());
  vertices.push(baseVector.clone().applyAxisAngle(axisVector, -step * i));
}
var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(vertices);
var colors = [];
var baseColor = new THREE.Color("gray");
var color = new THREE.Color("aqua");
for (let i = 1; i <= segs; i++) {
  let idx = (i - 1) * 6;
  baseColor.toArray(colors, idx);
  baseColor.toArray(colors, idx + 3);
}
geom.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));

var lines = new THREE.LineSegments(geom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
}));
scene.add(lines);

function setLineColor(idx, color) {
  geom.attributes.color.setXYZ(idx * 2, color.r, color.g, color.b);
  geom.attributes.color.setXYZ(idx * 2 + 1, color.r, color.g, color.b);
}

function getSec() {
  return new Date().getSeconds();
}

var prevSecond = getSec();
var currSecond = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  currSecond = getSec();
  if (prevSecond != currSecond) {
    setLineColor(currSecond, color);
    setLineColor(prevSecond, baseColor);
    geom.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
    prevSecond = currSecond;
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.min.js"></script>
```

Another option is to rotate a mesh (or its geometry, it's up to you):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var segs = 60;
var baseVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 5, 0);
var axisVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
var step = THREE.Math.degToRad(6);
var vertices = [];
for (var i = 0; i < segs; i++) {
  vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3());
  vertices.push(baseVector.clone().applyAxisAngle(axisVector, -step * i));
}
var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(vertices);
var colors = [];
var baseColor = new THREE.Color("gray");
var color = new THREE.Color("aqua");
for (let i = 1; i <= segs; i++) {
  let idx = (i - 1) * 6;
  baseColor.toArray(colors, idx);
  baseColor.toArray(colors, idx + 3);
}
geom.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));

var lines = new THREE.LineSegments(geom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
}));
scene.add(lines);

function setLineColor(idx, color) {
  geom.attributes.color.setXYZ(idx * 2, color.r, color.g, color.b);
  geom.attributes.color.setXYZ(idx * 2 + 1, color.r, color.g, color.b);
}

setLineColor(0, color);
geom.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
lines.rotation.z = -step * getSec();

function getSec() {
  return new Date().getSeconds();
}

var prevSecond = getSec();
var currSecond = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  currSecond = getSec();
  if (prevSecond != currSecond) {
    lines.rotation.z = -step * currSecond;
    prevSecond = currSecond;
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.min.js"></script>
```